# Overwrite $wp_customize from wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-theming

I am using a simple theme in WordPress, that pulls it's customizers sections from the plugin ThemeHunk Customizer.

I want to hide certain sections in the customizer section, but when using $wp_customize, it isn't working.

This is what I am trying to hide:

```
$wp_customize->add_section('section_home_ordering', array(
    'title'    => __('Section Ordering', 'featuredlite'),
    'priority' => 3,
));
```

This is located in the `/wp-content/plugins/themehunk-customizer/featuredlite/customizer/customizer.php` file.

I have added this to my functions.php file in my child theme directory:

```
function customize_register_init( $wp_customize ){
    $wp_customize->remove_section('section_default_home');
    $wp_customize->remove_section('pro_button');
    $wp_customize->remove_section('Docs_button');
    $wp_customize->remove_section('section_home_ordering'); - THIS IS THE SECTION I would like removed from the /plugin/ file
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'customize_register_init', 99 );
```

It doesn't seem to remove though, like it would if you were removing a section from a parent theme.

Is there another method to do this, or is this not possible to remove from a plugin rather than a parent theme?

Thank you in advance.

**SOLVED** I use the `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts` hook to input custom CSS within the wordpress customizer, so I can display certain elements as hidden!

Comment: As far as I know ThemHunk customize section includes options to hide certain section from the customize panel in Appearance > FrontPage Section customize. And more over it won't be ideal practice to remove section from plugin. You can simply can go with the css based solution using display: none; property for particular section using unique Id or Class.

Comment: @nir Thanks for your reply... there is no Appearance > FrontPage Section customize available.

Comment: Can you tell me which WordPress theme you are using ?

Comment: @nir OneLine Lite is the theme I am using.

Answer (score 0):

In theme your code works fine. Maybe it depends on action hooks order.
Have you tried?

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'customize_register_init', 99 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply go with these documentation as it shows you can disable particular section of Home Page (FrontPage). You can change order of appearance also from the Appearance > Frontpage Section > Section Ordering.

Reference Link: https://themehunk.com/docs/shopline-theme/#frontpage-section

https://themehunk.com/product/shopline-free-shopping-theme/

Comment: Thanks for the comment- this feature is not available in the theme I am using, hence why I wanted to remove the section via $wp_customize... I am assuming this is not possible though, as I haven't found anything on google.

Comment: You can hide particular section using css display: none; property. If you don't want to go with the code base solution

Comment: I have never done it via the customizer before with css, does this need to be done via the functions.php file?

Comment: No, you just need to inspect the element which you want to hide. 
Ref: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/

Comment: that's straight forward enough, and then I input the CSS in the child theme style.css file?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Take the unique element from the section you need to hide, otherwise if you take common Id or class name then every other element having same class or Id name will be also affected with the css. And after taking unique element and give that Id or class css display: none; and paste it to you child file's style.css.

Comment: Just tried that, and it didn't work.. I have tried this method in the past and a child theme style.css does not override wordpress customizer styles.

Comment: Try giving it ! important too. Example: .YourSectionClassName{ display: none !important;}

Comment: That did not work either... that's why I thought $wp_customize would of been best option.. not sure if there are other options.

Comment: Could you share you site's link ? And tell which section you want to hide?

Comment: I am currently working locally on my computer. Is there a hook for the customizer footer as could insert the CSS that way?